# Git/SourceTree - rollback or undo of pushed merge

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

all I want to do is delete or revert or rollback merge commit. I accidently merged master to another branch. And I also pushed it.

I tried "Reset current branch to this commit" option on the commit right under it. It just replaces my local files.

"Reverse commit" doesnt work on this merge commit. It shows:

```
error: commit 38be3abb5eddb981713b0f8e0d6e04ff9c720368 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

I even tried this command:

```
$ git revert -m 1 38be3abb5eddb981713b0f8e0d6e04ff9c720368
```

The response was:

```
On branch master

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is there any way how to reach this?

Answer (score 0):

Once a branch has been pushed, it's "too late". You can't rollback, it would just create a new commit on top but you won't be able to remerge your branch.

One option is to create a new branch just before the merge. Then remove `master` locally and remotely (you will probably have to force the removal, and sometimes you need to change the remote configuration when the repo has to have a master branch in bitbucket), then rename your branch to `master` and push it again.

If bitbucket is configured to require `master`, go in Settings and change the default branch to something else before removing the remote branch.